# Django rest framework custom filter backend data duplication

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to make my custom filter and ordering backend working with default search backend in django rest framework. The filtering and ordering working perfectly with each other, but when search is included in the query and i am trying to order query by object name, then data duplication is happening.

I tried to print queries and queries size, but it seems ok when i logging it in the filters, but in a response i have different object counts(ex. 79 objects in filter query, 170 duplicated objects in the final result)

Here is my filterset class

```
class PhonesFilterSet(rest_filters.FilterSet):
    brands = InListFilter(field_name='brand__id')
    os_ids = InListFilter(field_name='versions__os')
    version_ids = InListFilter(field_name='versions')
    launched_year_gte = rest_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='phone_launched_date__year', lookup_expr='gte')
    ram_gte = rest_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='internal_memories__value', method='get_rams')
    ram_memory_unit = rest_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='internal_memories__units', method='get_ram_units')

    def get_rams(self, queryset, name, value):
        #here is the problem filter
        #that not works with ordering by name
        q=queryset.filter(Q(internal_memories__memory_type=1) & Q(internal_memories__value__gte=value))
        print('filter_set', len(q))
        print('filter_set_query', q.query)
        return q


    def get_ram_units(self, queryset, name, value):
        return queryset.filter(Q(internal_memories__memory_type=1) & Q(internal_memories__units=value))


    class Meta:
        model = Phone
        fields = ['brands', 'os_ids', 'version_ids', 'status', 'ram_gte']
```

My ordering class:

```
class CustomFilterBackend(filters.OrderingFilter):
    allowed_custom_filters = ['ram', 'camera', 'year']

    def get_ordering(self, request, queryset, view):
        params = request.query_params.get(self.ordering_param)

        if params:
            fields = [param.strip() for param in params.split(',')]
            ordering = [f for f in fields if f in self.allowed_custom_filters]
            if ordering:
                return ordering

        # No ordering was included, or all the ordering fields were invalid

        return self.get_default_ordering(view)


    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        ordering = self.get_ordering(request, queryset, view)
        if ordering:
            if 'ram' in ordering:
                max_ram = Max('internal_memories__value', filter=Q(internal_memories__memory_type=1))
                queryset = queryset.annotate(max_ram=max_ram).order_by('-max_ram')
            elif 'camera' in ordering:
                max_camera = Max('camera_pixels__megapixels', filter=Q(camera_pixels__camera_type=0))    
                queryset = queryset.annotate(max_camera=max_camera).order_by('-max_camera')            
            elif 'year' in ordering:
                queryset = queryset.filter(~Q(phone_released_date=None)).order_by('-phone_released_date__year')
            elif 'name' in ordering:
                #here is the problem ordering
                #thats not working with filter
                #with one to many relations
                queryset = queryset.order_by('-brand__name', '-model__name')


        return queryset
```

Viewset class:

```
class PhoneViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Phone.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PhoneSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter, CustomFilterBackend, django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend)
    search_fields = ('brand__name', 'model__name')
    ordering_fields = ('brand__name', 'model__name')
    filter_class = PhonesFilterSet
```

As a result i am expecting no data duplication when i am applying ordering with filter and search. My question is why the number of objects is different in filter and in the response, where the data is becoming duplicated? I have no idea where to start debugging from this point. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please try `queryset = Phone.objects.all().distinct()` in `PhoneViewSet`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `distinct()` should fix this:

> Returns a new `QuerySet` that uses `SELECT DISTINCT` in its SQL query. This eliminates duplicate rows from the query results.
>
> By default, a `QuerySet` will not eliminate duplicate rows. In practice, this is rarely a problem, because simple queries such as `Blog.objects.all()` don’t introduce the possibility of duplicate result rows. However, if your query spans multiple tables, it’s possible to get duplicate results when a `QuerySet` is evaluated. That’s when you’d use `distinct()`.

Note however, that you still might get duplicate results:

> Any fields used in an `order_by()` call are included in the `SQL SELECT` columns. This can sometimes lead to unexpected results when used in conjunction with `distinct()`. If you order by fields from a related model, those fields will be added to the selected columns and they may make otherwise duplicate rows appear to be distinct. Since the extra columns don’t appear in the returned results (they are only there to support ordering), it sometimes looks like non-distinct results are being returned.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct

If you are using PostgreSQL, you can specify the names of fields to which the `DISTINCT` should apply. This might help. (I'm not sure.) For more on this, see the link above.

So, I'd `return queryset.distinct()` in the methods where you commented that you get issues. I would not apply it always (as I had written in my comment above for debugging) because you don't need it for simple queries.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with ordering by a related field. I wanted to order my items by the created date of a related model, that had a foreign key to my original model.

This is how I was able to do it without duplication:

```
from django.db import models

from .models import MyModel

MyModel.objects.annotate(
    publications_created=models.Min("publications__created")
).order_by("publications_created")
```

This is specific to my use case, but you can use `annotate` to build a proper query and then `order_by` that value. It seems this way there is no duplication of items, specifically with Django Rest Framework.